# Staying logged in after logging out with Express and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am having a problem with logging out of my application.

I am using MongoDB to store my sessions.

I log out by using session.destroy and the document gets removed from the collection in the database. However I still remained logged in. Also the cookie in the browser still exists, surely this should expire. I believe my authentication is using the cookie in the browser to check authentication and since that is still there, it keeps me logged in.

Here is my authentication code:

**app.js**

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'whatshouldmysecretkeybe',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 86400000
  },
  resave: false,
  unset: 'destroy',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));
```

**loginController.js**

```
// Authenticated Check
exports.requires_login = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session && req.session.userId) {
        return next();
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/cms/unauthenticated');
        return;
    }
}

exports.logout = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session) {
        // delete session object
        req.session.destroy(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return res.redirect('/cms/');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Route file**

I put the login_controller.requires_login middleware on the route to check for authentication on every route that needs authentication. I hope this is the best way to do this.

```
/* GET Login authenticate */
router.get('/users/logout', login_controller.requires_login, login_controller.logout);

/* GET User listing page */
router.get('/users', login_controller.requires_login, user_controller.list);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue was due to mongoose 5 not being fully compatible with connect-mongo.

This github issue explains more:

https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/issues/277

To fix you have to use your mongo url in the url property instead of mongooseConnection.

Example:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'whatshouldmysecretkeybe',
  resave: false,
  unset: 'destroy',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    url: YOUR_MONGO_URL
  })
}));
```